# Uncaught TypeError: i18next.init is not a function

Tags: typescript, i18next

I'm using typescript for my project, and using i18next for internalization.

typescript: v2.1.4

i18next: v2.3.4

@types/i18next: v2.3.35

in my file:

```
import * as i18next from 'i18next';

i18next.init({
    lng: 'en',
    resources: {
        en: {
            translation: {
                "key": "hello world"
            }
        }
    }
}, (err, t) => {
    // initialized and ready to go!
    const hw = i18next.t('key'); // hw = 'hello world'
});
```

however, in browser it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: i18next.init is not a function
```

if I log the i18next object, it looks like:

[image]

and in console

```
i18n.default.init
```

works well.

If import like document

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
```

in visual studio code will complains:
[image]

my .tsconfig

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": false,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node",
            "poly2tri",
            "three",
            "i18next"
        ]
    }
}
```

my webpack.config.js is just too long to read.

I wonder is something relate to the document: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html

```
/*~ Note that ES6 modules cannot directly export class objects.
 *~ This file should be imported using the CommonJS-style:
 *~   import x = require('someLibrary');
 *~
 *~ Refer to the documentation to understand common
 *~ workarounds for this limitation of ES6 modules.
 */
```

Comment: How do you run your code in browser? I tested it (in NodeJS) and the init function is there with `import * as i18next from 'i18next'`

Comment: I'm using `i18next@7.1.0` thou

Comment: I'm using webpack.

Comment: Because the @types/i18next is for 2.3.4, i just stuck with this version.

Comment: I tested with 2.3.4, and it is still working. Seems like you may have issue with your setup. Can you post your `tsconfig.json` and webpack config?

Comment: I add my tsconfig.json, did this means anything to you?

Comment: it that relate to my file is .tsx?

Comment: There are some extra stuff but I think it should be ok. One thing is trying to compile in es5 instead and see what happens. It is not related to tsx. I do guess it is more related to webpack thou. Will try your config tomorrow. Also, will pose an answer on a simplified version of your tsconfig tomorrow.

Comment: thanks a lot, for now, my workaround is copy the @types/i18next index.d.ts file to my working dir, and change the last line to 'export default i18n', which is originally 'export = i18n'. in my index.tsx file, using 'import i18n from 'i18n'' instead, and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link in your question. I didn't know that template existed.

I believe that is not related to your problem. That is for writing typings in es6 modules that describe a commonjs module, which directly export a class.

From your workaround, it does sound like interop issue between TypeScript and Babel. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7398
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8687

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is related to

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7398

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8687

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1587

What happen is the module resolution syntax in TypeScript and Babel/NodeJS is different.

In Babel/NodeJS (latest draft), CommonJS module is imported using the syntax:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
```

i.e. the CommonJS module is moved to the `default` export of ES6 module.

However, TypeScript does not follow this route:

```
import * as i18n from 'i18next'
```

Therefore, when compiled by `tsc` to `es6`, this import statement remain as is.
Thus Babel does the wrong thing.

Please help by rising your voice in those issues above to get more attention from the teams.

This issue should really be a P1 and fix asap.

For now, one solution is to compile your code down to es5 through `tsc` instead.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

In `i18next` version [`17.0.0+`](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1700) you have to import it this way:

```
import { default as i18n } from 'i18next';
```

In `tsconfig.js` set `"esModuleInterop": true` to make it work with `jest`.

Other module options I have in my `tsconfig.js` (not sure if all of them are needed to make it work):

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es6",
```

#### Explanation

[In `v17.0.0` `i18next` changed how the module is exported](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1700):

> - removes named exports in main file - avoids issues in mixed exports makes usage better in commonjs scenarios (node.js) - no strange const i18next = require('i18next').default;
> - impact you can't no longer import { changeLanguage } from 'i18next'; changeLanguage('de'); you will have to import i18next from 'i18next'; i18next.changeLanguage('de');

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with v17.0.0 as in the question Alen says he is using a much older version v2.3.4 and I tried downgrading to v15.1.3 and I'm still getting this error.